# How do I fix gcc not found error when cross compiling the linux kernel for beaglebone black

Tags: linux, kernel, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I am trying to cross-compile the Linux kernel for the beaglebone black on Ubuntu 22.04 using the command line below:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- bb.org_defconfig
```

I get the following error:

```
HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:90: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:467: scripts_basic] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:633: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
```

As a result of various searches, I have verified that I have arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc in /bin:

```
/bin$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*gcc*" -print

./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ranlib-11
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-11
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-nm
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ranlib
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-nm-11
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar-11
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib-11
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-11
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ar
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm-11
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar
./arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ar-11
```

that my path includes /bin:

```
echo $PATH
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: When cross-compiling Linux kernel, you need not only a *cross-compiler*, but a compiler (`gcc`) for your **host** too.

---

When build the Linux kernel and modules, the build system not only compiles binaries for the target platform, but also **executes** some **programs** on these binaries. These programs are shipped with the Linux kernel sources as sources, so for build these programs **host compiler** is needed.

By the way, a line started with HOSTCC means that exactly host compiler is used for that operation.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks